# How to implement Caesar cipher-like text substitution in Vim?

Tags: vim

I was doing some puzzle where each English letter is replaced by the one two letters down the alphabet. For example, the word `apple` is to be transformed into `crrng`, as `a` + 2 → `c`, `b` + 2 → `d`, etc.

In Python, I was able to implement this transformation using the `maketrans()`
string method. I wonder: Is it possible to do the same via search and replace in Vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** If the alphabetic characters are arranged sequentially in the target
encoding (as is the case for ASCII and some alphabets in UTF-8, like
English), one can use the following substitution command:

```
:%s/./\=nr2char(char2nr(submatch(0))+2)/g
```

(Before running the command, make sure that the `encoding` option
is set accordingly.)

However, this replacement implements a non-circular letter shift.
A circular shift can be implemented by two substitutions separately
handling lowercase and uppercase letters:

```
:%s/\l/\=nr2char(char2nr('a') + (char2nr(submatch(0)) - char2nr('a') + 2) % 26)/g
:%s/\u/\=nr2char(char2nr('A') + (char2nr(submatch(0)) - char2nr('A') + 2) % 26)/g
```

**2.** Another way is to translate characters using the `tr()` function.
Let us assume that the variable `a` contains lowercase characters
of an alphabet arranged in correct order, and the variable `a1` hold
the string of characters corresponding to those in `a` (below is
an example for English letters).

```
:let a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
:let a1 = a[2:] . a[:1]
```

To avoid typing the whole alphabet by hand, the value of `a` can be
produced as follows:

```
:let a = join(map(range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z')), 'nr2char(v:val)'), '')
```

Then, to replace each letter on a line by the letter two positions down
the alphabet, one can use the following substitution:

```
:%s/.*/\=tr(submatch(0), a . toupper(a), a1 . toupper(a1))
```

Comment: Thanks.. But if i want to have circular replace.. like y->a z->b is it possible in one single line?

Comment: just a small remark: the `.` that concatenates string makes it hard to read when you code in C++, I would prefer it padded with spaces both sides (seems that you didn't golf it this times, given the spaces after commas!)

Comment: @Benoit:  There is no point in squeezing the last command itself, since it depends on other two defining `a` and `a1`.  Regarding concatenations, personally, I would like not to surround concatenation operator with spaces in this case.  Without spaces it is easier to grasp boundaries of function arguments.  However, because the answer is most useful for those new to Vim scripting, it is probably better to add spaces around the dot operators.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `\=` will execute the function

```
%s/\(.\)/\=nr2char(char2nr(submatch(1)) + 2)/g
```

Comment: no need to use a matching group, see ib.'s solution. `submatch(0)` will match the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of anything in vim, but you could use the unix command line utility 'tr' (stands for translate, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

The puzzle you describe is widely known as the caesar cipher, and is normally implemented via the `tr` command or `sed -e y/`. Since y is not available in vim, you'll need a pretty dirty hack like ib proposed, but calling tr is much nicer work.

Especially considering the corner case of y and z: I assume these should be mapped to a and b, respectively?